# ajax request from JavaScript to asp.net MVC core 6 controller not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am using asp.net core 6 to send JavaScript request to controller for adding data but its not responding and after data: command it jumps to error section

```
$.ajax({
    url: routeURL + '/api/Appointment/SaveCalendarData',
    type: 'Post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            console.log(response);
            //$notify(response.message, "success");
            onCloseModal();
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error");
            //$notify(response.message, "error");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Error error log");
    }
});
```

here is the request data from where data is coming from razor in request Data Function

```
function onSubmitForm() {
var requestData = {
    Id: parseInt($("#id").val()),
    Title: $("#title").val(),
    Description: $("#description").val(),
    StartDate: $("#appointmentDate").val(),
    Duration: $("#duration").val(),
    DoctorId: $("#doctorid").val(),
    PatientId: $("#patientId").val()
}
console.log(requestData);
```

and here is the controller side but JavaScript request doesn't hit controller side

```
    namespace AppointmentSchedule.Controllers.Api
{
    [Route("api/Appointment")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AppointmentApiController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAppointmentService _appointmentService;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly string loginUserId;
        private readonly string role;
        public AppointmentApiController(IAppointmentService appointmentService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, string loginUserId)
        {
            _appointmentService = appointmentService;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            loginUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            role = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("SaveCalendarData")]
        public JsonResult SaveCalendarData(AppointmentVM data)
        {
            CommonResponse<int> commonResponse = new CommonResponse<int>();
            try
            {
                commonResponse.status = _appointmentService.AddUpdate(data).Result;
                if (commonResponse.status == 1) 
                {
                    commonResponse.message = Helper.Helper.appointmentUpdated;
                }
                if (commonResponse.status == 2)
                {
                    commonResponse.message = Helper.Helper.appointmentAdded;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                commonResponse.message = e.Message;
                commonResponse.status = Helper.Helper.failure_code;
            }
            return Json(commonResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

and last its Program.cs file

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAppointmentService, AppointmentService>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

[image: here is the Network response error message where its throwing 500]

Comment: Please put complete the `controller` and `startup` class code so I can help you

Comment: how can i send you here sir ? its not pasting code

Comment: Edit your question and complete the codes you entered ,If you don't have a startup class, put the code of the program class and the controller

Comment: done sir can you please check now

Comment: I checked your code. There is no routing problem in it. It seems like there is an error in the logic codes of your program. Check the response server in the developer tools section of the browser and place it here.

Comment: its throwing 500 error sir

Comment: Debug your code or see the response section in the browser, where the error details are mentioned

Comment: okay sir let me check again because i debug javascript in browser source section and its jump to error section without going through success section
and response in console was 500

Comment: I don't mean the console tab,find the request in the network tab  and click on and  see the response

Comment: sir i have updated question kindly check network response thanks for your help sir

Comment: In this picture, I have specified where to come to see :  https://iili.io/rKBBou.png

Comment: oops sorry its specifying (Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'AppointmentSchedule.Controllers.Api.AppointmentApiController'.)

Comment: i send a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `loginUserId` from  constructor parameters  as follows:

```
 public AppointmentApiController(IAppointmentService appointmentService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
 {
    _appointmentService = appointmentService;
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
     loginUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
     role = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);
  }
```

Comment: oops My Bad
Thanks Alot Bro 
u guided me well
and saved my time

Comment: I was thinking about everything except this ;) good luck

Answer (score 3):

1. Please check if there is any JS error in your browser console, If any please fix it accordingly.
2. Check for the network response or status after the AJAX call, It'll give you a clue about the issue.
3. If you get 405 status code maybe it's happening because of Antiforgery Token. If you don't want to validate the request just add `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` in your action method, or provide the anti-forgery token during the Ajax call `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

Ex:

```
fetch(postUrl, {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'RequestVerificationToken': '@AntiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: I have debugged in browser source After data:Json.stringify(requestdata) its jumps to error: command and throwing 500 in browser console

Answer (score -2):

Try the code like below:

```
<input id="id" name="Id" />

<input id="title" name="Title" />

<button onclick="postdata1()">submit(jsondata)</button>

   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function postdata1() {
 var a = [];            
 var requestData = { Id: parseInt($("#id").val()),Title: $("#title").val()};
 a.push(requestData);
var data = JSON.stringify(a);
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Appointment/SaveCalendarData',
    type:  "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },   
    dataType: "json",
    data:data,
   }).done(function(data) {
            });
            }
    </script>
```

Add `[FromBody] List<AppointmentVM> data` in your action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("SaveCalendarData")]
        public JsonResult SaveCalendarData([FromBody] List<AppointmentVM> data)
        {
            ....//do your staff
        }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: you mean to say i should put Javascript in razor page instead of separate Javascript page ?

Comment: I don't mean this. I just use the part of your code and try to reproduce your problem and try to help you solve it. Though my answer is not your want, I spend my time too. Sadly, I loss my scores.

Comment: Thnaks but i havent voted against you, thanks for the help

Comment: @QingGuo Unfortunately, your answer has nothing to do with the question, please check it first and then send an answer